able to execute pyspark script in pycharm terminal using virtual env, but execution failing on pycharm run, in mac
/Users//spark/spark-3.5.2-bin-hadoop3/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java: Not a directory
/Users//spark/spark-3.5.2-bin-hadoop3/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript
head: illegal line count -- -1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects/pythonPro/pp.py", line 5, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects/pythonPro/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 497, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects/pythonPro/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 515, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects/pythonPro/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 201, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects/pythonPro/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 436, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects/pythonPro/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 107, in launch_gateway

    raise PySparkRuntimeError(
pyspark.errors.exceptions.base.PySparkRuntimeError: [JAVA_GATEWAY_EXITED] Java gateway process exited before sending its port number.

same is executing fine in terminal(pycharm), I have tried verifying environment variables, PYTHONPATH, JAVA_HOME, SPARK_HOME, all are same as configured in zsh .
I added /bin/zsh -l in configurations as well to load the settings at runtime, but nothing is working, please can anybody help on this.
I am using mac os
I have tried verifying environment variables, PYTHONPATH, JAVA_HOME, SPARK_HOME, all are same as configured in zsh .
I added /bin/zsh -l in configurations as well to load the settings at runtime, but nothing is working, please can anybody help on this.

Have you installed a recent JDK? Where? And how have you set your JAVA_HOME? Because that's what isn't working (according to the messages).

yes I have installed JDK, setting JAVA_HOME to value:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.24/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home, against /usr/libexec/java_home
tried with both, /usr/libexec/java_home and /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.24/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home

Neither of those look right. JAVA_HOME should be set to the folder that contains bin. Also, $JAVA_HOME/bin needs to be added to your path.

@ElliottFrisch, I updated JAVA_HOME to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.24/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
still getting the same. Please tell me where to find the correct JAVA_HOME from, if this is wrong

I feel pycharm is not able to identify the java in system. I and using the same env variables in zsh, and script is running in terminal
